# Как в Eclipse/CDT указать расположение папки со своими *.h файлами

Tags: cdt, include, eclipse, c++

Как в Eclipse/CDT указать расположение папки со своими заголовочными файлами?

Например, у меня есть две созданные мной папки в проекте, расположенные на одном уровне иерархии: src и include. Исходники хранятся в src, а *.h файлы в include. Я хочу в исходнике писать так:

```
#include "*.h"
```

А не так:

```
#include "../include/*.h"
```

Что мне нужно сделать, что бы Eclipse включил папку include как свою переменную окружения, что ли?

Заранее благодарю всех, кто поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши на проекте щёлкнуть, там Properties, и (для других компиляторов - аналогичные настройки):
[image]

Comment: Ok! Спасибо большое, стало много легче.